# External editor in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, editor, external

Is there any way to set up external editor integration for VS2008?

By this I mean when I double-click on a .CPP file in the Solution Explorer, it should open in the external editor, not the internal VS one.

To keep it simple let's say I want it to open the file in Notepad++ (or how about Notepad to make it even simpler).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right click on the type of file you want in the Solution Explorer,

Then choose Open With...

Pick your program, and choose "Set as Default"

Comment: Thanks! I can't figure out how to pass arguments, any ideas? (i want to pass --servername VS_NET --remote-silent when opening with GVim.exe).

Answer (score 3):

Right click on any file and choose open with..

Then click on add to browse to the program of you choice for this file type and having added it to the list, select "set as default"

From now on when you double click on this file type it will open in the editor of your choice.

Comment: Thanks Richard, you also provided a perfect answer but Reed just beat you to it :)

Answer (score 0):

(In VS2008)

You can goto: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extension. Put a file extension in and choose a program to launch with it

Comment: I tried that list but it doesn't contain Notepad and I can't see a way of adding it.